# InvocationTargetException in JavaFX Applicacation Thread

Tags: java, javafx, invocationtargetexception

When I click a button in my program which is supposed to send the data to a database i get this error:

```
    Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ControllerMethodEventHandler.handle(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(Unknown Source)
    ... 108 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at controller.RegisterController.reg(RegisterController.java:23)
    ... 60 more
```

Here is part of the  code itself:

```
package controller;

public class RegisterController {

  public void initialize() {}

  public void reg(){
      String gender = null;

     line 23 ----> if(radioMale.isPressed()){
          gender = "male";
      }
      if(radioFemale.isPressed()){
          gender = "female";
      }

      String query = "INSERT INTO Main (USERNAME,PASSWORD,BirthDate,Gender) VALUES (" + "'" + username.getText() +
              "'," + "'" + password.getText() + "'," + "'" + date_picker.getValue() + "'," + "'" + gender + "');";

      insertStatement(query);
  }
```

P.S. I removed quite a lot from the code and error since the site didn't let me post it with so much code. But I belive the problem should be here somewhere

Comment: Don't build SQL via string concatenation. Use a PreparedStatement.

Comment: At least one of the following is null: `radioMale`, `radioFemale`, `username`, `password` or `date_picker `. Only you can know which, by debugging.

Comment: Thanks Andy that worked perfect!